# Is it possible to find a supersequence of a single array?

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, arrays

In Jeff Erickson's *Algorithms* textbook, the chapter on Dynamic Programming asks you to "Describe an efficient algorithm to compute the length of the shortest
oscillating supersequence of an arbitrary array A of integers".

A supersequence contains all of the elements from the original array X[1...n], and oscillating is defined as X [i] < X [i + 1] for all even i, and X [i] > X [i + 1] for all odd i.

However, I am not asking about the answer to this problem. I am just wondering if this question even is sound. How can you find a supersequence of a single array? Wouldn't the answer just be the length of the original array if all elements are oscillating? Else, 0. Usually, a supersequence is found between multiple arrays.

Answer (score 1):

What about the array $[1, 3, 5]$? The supersequence $[0,1,0,3,0,5]$ is oscillating while the original sequence isn’t. In fact you can make an oscillating supersequence of any array by inserting $\min(arr)-1$ before every element of the original array.